# South migrations and changes to many-to-may fields

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-south

I was working on an app that is supposed to send newsletters to customers. I had a model defined like this

```
from django.auth.models import User

class Newsletter(models.Model):                                                                  
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', blank=False)                                                                                                                                                  
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                                                                                                                                                       
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                                                                                                                                          
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True)                                                                                                                                                                     
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)                                                                                                                                                                      
    content = HTMLField()                                                                                                                                                                                           
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='+')
```

Later on, I found out that I might need to send these to people who do not have user accounts, so I defined an email model

```
class Email(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                          
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and changed the recipients field to read

```
recipients = models.ManyToManyField(Email, related_name='+')
```

After this, I ran schemamigration command, but South claimed that there are no changes. I have made several attempts to manually manipulate tables and indexes, but at some point figured that since it is a new app, I can just drop all the existing tables, remove all igrations and recreate initial migration from scratch. This poses a question though, how do I do a migration like this if I really need to preserve the data.

Comment: Did south notice the new `Email` model?

Comment: Yes, it did. But it didn't notice anything about the M2M link.

Comment: See the previous migration's freeze and see if the change isn't there already. Sometimes if you make changes to model and do some datamigrations meanwhile this happens.

Comment: There were no other migrations, just the initial and the change I described.

Comment: Try creating a Newsletter instance in shell and see if you get any error, I remember experiencing something similar and in creation went normal.

Comment: When I try to run the dev server I get all sorts of errors related to M2M link and wrong field names, wrong constraints etc. They happen when I try to manipulate recipients in some way.

Comment: I'm having this same issue right now. Since South did not see the m2m change, the database still points to your old table on the m2m table. I'm searching more, but I suspect I'll have to write 3 migrations scripts for this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve data you will need to split it into 3 migrations (schema, data, schema) like this:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.add_column(
            u'yourapp_newsletter_recipients',
            'email_id',
            self.gf(
                'django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey'
            )(to=orm.Email)
        )
```

Notice that you should have your old schema in the migration's models property.

Then your data migration that fills the email field. Then schema migration again:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.delete_column(u'yourapp_newsletter_recipients', 'user_id')
```

In this one you should already have correct m2m field for recipients field in the migration's models['newslatter']