# Migrating ManyToManyField to null true, blank true, isn't recognized

Tags: django, django-models, database-schema, django-south, django-migrations

I have made a model change from

```
standard = models.ManyToManyField(Standard)
```

to

```
standard = models.ManyToManyField(Standard, blank=True, null=True)
```

South schemamigration for this app doesn't recognize the change?

Similar to this question, which is unanswered:
[South migrations and changes to many-to-may fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755119/south-migrations-and-changes-to-many-to-may-fields)

Comment: What exactly does South say when you try to run `./manage.py schemamigration yourapp --auto`?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you aren't saving `models.py`, but I highly doubt it. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: Just a thought: should south do something? A ManyToManyField will create an intermediate table, so its either you have a record in that table or not. I mean both fk columns should still be mandatory on the intermediate table. Sorry if I got this wrong!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

That behavior is correct: `null` doesn't mean anything at the database level when used with a `ManyToManyField`. The declaration of a `ManyToManyField` causes the creation of an intermediate table to hold the relationship, and although Django will create a `standard` attribute on your model instance for your convenience, there is no actual column representing it that could be nulled. By definition there can always be zero instances of the relationship.

`blank=False`, though, does have an effect on validation (when using model forms like the admin app, for example), forcing the user to choose at least one relation.

(Note that Django's built-in migration system creates migrations for just about any change to a model, regardless of whether it affects the database or not. So this change could lead to a migration, but it wouldn't affect the database or whether or not you could have zero instances of the relationship.)